# VBA excel Create a dynamic searching using combobox

Tags: excel, vba, list, dynamic, combobox

I will need your help. I have the following case.

**Sheet2 :**
**column A** list of products  (examples: spray black 01, spray black 02, spray red 01, spray red 02, colour red 01, colour red 02  etc)
**column B** has the categories of products (examples: spray, colour etc)

1. A inputbox appears and the user enters the category
2. A combobox appears and the user has to select from the list or products of the category the correct product **OR** by typing a key see below the list changes.

**Example : **
the user enters in input box the key "spray"
then in combobox the user will see a list only with sprays.
then if he writes red the list will change and brings only the red spays.

Is it possible ?

*please see below the screen of what i am trying to do[image]
**First point :** the number of items per list are not always the same, so I have to create dynamic ranges.
**second point** is that for the first combobox i need unique values for example brings me only one time the value "spray" when the bropbox opens and shows the items of the list.
**the third point** is that as you can see in the second combobox when i am typing red i would like to have only the red sprays. Is this possible ?
Thank you all,*

how can i add the file here ?

Comment: Definitely possible - give it a try then post back if you run into problems (and include your code along with a description of any error messages etc)

Comment: @Zounds check this out http://www.contextures.com/exceldatavaldependindextablesindirect.html

Comment: Definitely look into exploring how to create a userform in excel, you'll have to lay it out yourself, then once it's created you/we can put some code behind it...

Comment: thanks you guys I ll follow your advices and I ll be back with more data :)

Comment: hello guys please the above i have added some more comments and datas in my initial topic. Thank you in advance for your help